# SQL retrieve joined data an array

Tags: mysql

I have the following database structure:

**users:**

```
id
name
```

**user_activities:**

```
user_id
activity_id
```

**activities:**

```
id
name
```

I'm trying to write a Select query that will output the following:

```
 - user1.id, activities: {[activity.id, activity.name], ['activity.id, activity.name]};
 - user2.id, activities: {[activity.id, activity.name], ['activity.id, activity.name]};
```

I know how to do it in two steps, but I have many users and selecting activities for each one is heavy. Is there way to do it with one MySQL query?

Comment: there's no sense to attempt constructing an array notation on MySql query level. You can convert needed data from the result  after it was fetched. I can suggest a solution to get grouped data with one query, if you are interested

Comment: grouped data sounds like something I need actually; it would be great if you could suggest a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `GROUP_CONCAT` function with `SEPARATOR` option, which lets you get all activities for a certain user:

```
SELECT u.id, GROUP_CONCAT( a.id,  "|", a.name
SEPARATOR  ', ' ) AS useractivities
FROM  `users` u
INNER JOIN  `user_activities` ua ON u.id = ua.user_id
INNER JOIN  `activities` a ON a.id = ua.activity_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

This query will return a resultset in such state:

```
id | useractivities
------------------------------------
79 | 17|sport
18 | 3|music, 19|outing, 17|sport
.. | ....
```

Then, while fetching each row from resultset you can easily explode(split) the `useractivities` field value by comma(as delimiter) and thus, get all activities for a certain user